# "match with" or "match in" in phrase like "Match with skills"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english, conjunctions, british-english

Suppose there's person whose some qualities match with you. You have to write this in a phrase to show percentage. What I mean is this:

Match *with/in/not sure* quality_1: 78%

Match *with/in/not sure* quality_2: 68%

What is a correct way to write a pharse like above? (I woudn't mind if you change the phrase to make it correct and still having same meaning.)

Comment: "Qualities that match - 78%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching qualities: 68%
Percentage Match: 68%
Quality Match: 68%
Qualities that match: 68%

Matching Skills: 68%
Percentage Match: 68%
Skills Match: 68%
Skills that match: 68%

Comment: Thank you. There response was late though.